# Websockets is not returning any data

Tags: angular, websocket, asp.net-core-signalr

I am facing an issue with websocket. Actually I have an SPA application having Angular as front-end and .Net core as back-end.

When user logs into the application socket starts the connection but it doesn't return any data. I have Azure app service and websocket is enable under configuration. Also it works in my local environment.

I have tried to return the id of connected user to ensure that it gets connected but I am not receiving that message from socket. Below code snippet is what I am doing on connection.

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        var connectionid = Context.ConnectionId;
        log.Info("OnConnectedAsync: Connecting..." + connectionid);
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionid, name);
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("UserConnected", name, connectionid);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        log.Info("OnConnectedAsync: Connected..." + connectionid);
}
```

Here is the code from front-end where I am creating socket connection.

```
this.dashboardHubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(environment.baseApi + '/' + hubname, { accessTokenFactory: () => token })
        .build();
      this.dashboardHubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Dashboard Connection started');
          this.registerDashboardSignalREvents();
          this.addDashboardListner();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting dashboard connection: ' + err))

public addDashboardListner() {
this.dashboardHubConnection.on('UserConnected', (user, conId) => {
  this.userId = user;
  let connectionId = conId;
  if (this.userId) {
    this.dashboardHubConnection.invoke('fetchdata', this.userId, connectionId)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
  console.log("Connection id : " + connectionId + " for user : " + this.userId);
});
```

}

but I am getting only one message Dashboard Connection Started and that's it no other message. I am also sharing the network image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28MtK.png)

Any kind of help will be appreciated. I don't know what is missing here. Thank you for the help !

Comment: Add below lines just before build on front-end code where you are creating connection. it will log more information on console.

Comment: .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                               {
                                   logging.Services.AddLogging(l => l.AddConsole());                    
                                   logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                                   logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Debug);
                                   logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections", LogLevel.Debug);
                               })